# Recursive fibonacci-like functions in Sympy

Tags: recursion, sympy

How can I define a recursive function in Sympy, like the fibonacci function so its engine can perform simplifications on it?
I.e. `f(0)=0, f(1)=1, f(x)=f(x-1) + f(x-2)`

It looks like Sympy's `Piecewise` might be needed, but I don't see how to express recursion.

I got this far:

```py
from sympy import *

x=symbols('x')
f=Function('f')
f=Piecewise((0, Eq(x,0)), (1, Eq(x,1)), (f(x-1)+f(x-2), True))
f
f.subs(x,10)
```

The evaluation of line `f` looks fine:
[image: evaluation of line <code>f</code>]

But the last line evaluates to `f(8)+f(9)` which is of course not what I want because it cannot be simplified further.

I know that the fibonacci function is already defined, but I need it for something similar not for fibonacci itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `rsolve` (though the version I tested doesn't recognize the Fibonacci function) but if that fails you might consider a memoized function:

```
>>> from sympy.strategies.core import memoize
>>> @memoize
... def f(x):
...     if x == 0:return 0
...     if x == 1:return 1
...     return f(x-1)+f(x-2)
>>> f(10)
55
>>> f(8)+f(9)
55
```

Comment: I do not want to have a normal python function but rather doing symbolic manipulation. (Like I can with the built in fibonacci function.) E.g. my expression would contain symbols, hoping that I can find the closed form formula of my (multivariate) function. E.g. `simplify(f(x-2)+f(x-3))` would evaluate to `f(x-1)`

Comment: You could look at how `fibonacci` was defined to get some ideas on how to implement your own Function. You would have to know the types of valid transformations so you could implement them in an `eval` method.